# Standard maven layout for a web application, do my .properties files go?

Tags: maven-2, maven

Assuming I have a .properties file and hibernate.cfg.xml in a standard maven web application layout where should they be placed so that they are included in my .war file when I run package?

src/main/resources

src/main/java

src/main/webapp

src/main/config

?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Application/Library resources go in `src/main/resources` (they will end up in `target/classes` first after compilation and then in `WEB-INF/classes` in the war after packaging).

#### See also

- [Introduction to the Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

Comment: For others who are lost check this http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html